# SonarQube issue: Rename this constant name to match the regular expression '^[A-Z][A-Z0-9](_[A-Z0-9]+)$'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube

I have created this enum class

```
public enum StreetNameEnum {
  StreetOwner("0"), StreetedBy("1"), StreetedFor("2"), RegisteredBy("3"), StreetContact("4"), AssignedTo("5");
  private String code;
  StreetRoleEnum(String code) {}
  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }
}
```

SonarQube issue:

> Rename this constant name to match the regular expression
>   '^[A-Z]A-Z0-9$'.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It means your constants are supposed to match this regular expression:

`^[A-Z][A-Z0-9](_[A-Z0-9]+)$`

Which basically means, only use upper case characters, numbers and underscores (in the order which is valid Java syntax). So instead of `StreetOwner`, use `STREET_OWNER`. `RegisteredBy` should be `REGISTERED_BY` and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I think by the convention, your `StreetOwner("0"), StreetedBy("1"), StreetedFor("2"), RegisteredBy("3"), StreetContact("4"), AssignedTo("5");` All of these should be in capital letter for all character.